# How to create multiple spoiler buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When building my website, I decided I wanted to add a show/hide (spoiler) section in order to conserve space. Here is my "working" code:

### JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //Waits for page load
    $("a.spoilerButton, a.spoilerButtonDark").click(function () { //Attaches listeners
        $($(this).attr('href')).slideToggle(1000, null); //Open/closes spoiler
    });
});
```

### CSS:

```
a.spoilerButton,
a.spoilerButtonDark {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}
a.spoilerButton:hover,
a.spoilerButtonDark:hover {
    color:grey;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a.spoiler {
    display:none;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<div id="spoiler1" class="spoiler">Content</div> <!--Spoiler-->

<div class="contentBoxFooter">
    <a href="#spoiler1" class = "spoilerButton">Show/Hide</a> <!--Button-->
</div>
```

### What I would like:

- Support for multiple buttons
- A way to link the buttons to its appropriate spoiler at any place in the HTML

### Problems I am facing:

- Don't exactly know the proper way to link the button to its appropriate spoiler, or if I'm
  doing it completely wrong
- Current method uses href in anchor tag which shifts the page scroll location whenever clicked on

### Main Question:

I thought about using the ID tag in the anchor tag to tell the script what the spoiler ID was, although I don't think ID tags were intended for that. Is that how I should go about doing this, or is it not the proper way to do it?

Comment: can you create the fiddle for your problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if i understand your question correctly.
On this page there are four links that open the respective spoiler tags.
This is just a simple example, I hope it can help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
.spoiler {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.contentBoxFooter{position:absolute;bottom:10px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="a1" class="spoiler">Content</div> 
    <div id="a2" class="spoiler">Content</div>
    <div id="a3" class="spoiler">Content</div>
    <div id="a4" class="spoiler">Content</div>
    <div class="contentBoxFooter">
        <a href="a1" class = "spoilerButton">Show/Hide</a>
        <a href="a2" class = "spoilerButton">Show/Hide</a>
        <a href="a3" class = "spoilerButton">Show/Hide</a>
        <a href="a4" class = "spoilerButton">Show/Hide</a>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".spoilerButton").click(function (e) { 
            e.preventDefault()
            var foo=$(this).attr('href')
            $('#'+foo).slideToggle(1000); 
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I didn't know you could cancel events, and I also didn't know if I was doing it right by using anchor tags in the first place.

Comment: The only flaw in similar script is that you is forced to use specific ids for your spoiler div.With this other solution no.    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".spoilerButton").click(function (e) { 
            e.preventDefault()
   var ind=$(this).index()
   //first method
            $('.spoiler:nth-child('+(ind+1)+')').slideToggle(1000); 
   //second method
   /*$('.spoiler:eq('+(ind)+')').slideToggle(1000); */
   //third method
   /*var a=$('.spoiler').get()[ind].id
   $('#'+a).slideToggle(1000);*/
        });
    });
    </script>