# Open spoiler on a separate page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my website, I have to build multiple spoilers. I'm planning to use this code for creating spoilers: [How to create multiple spoiler buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624782/how-to-create-multiple-spoiler-buttons#tab-top).

I'm looking for an easy way to create a link **'x'** on a page **'A.html'** that leads to the page **'B.html'** and opens the spoiler **'x'** on the page **'B.html'**. So the spoiler **name="x"** and the URL should look similar to **B.html#x**.

In other words, I need a table of contents on the page **A.html** for spoilers on the page **B.html**.

But if you go straight to the page **B.html**, all spoilers should be closed by default with an option to open and close them by clicking on the spoiler title.

Any ready-made solutions would be appreciated. The solution shouldn't necessarily be based on the code I provided above.

Ok, I know that it's totally wrong, but this is what I tried.

**A.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
.spoiler {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.contentBoxFooter{position:absolute;bottom:10px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="x" class="spoiler">Content1</div> 
    <div id="y" class="spoiler">Content2</div>
    <div id="z" class="spoiler">Content3</div>
    <div class="contentBoxFooter">
        <a href="B.html#x" class = "spoilerButton">Show/Hide</a>
        <a href="B.html#y" class = "spoilerButton">Show/Hide</a>
        <a href="B.html#z" class = "spoilerButton">Show/Hide</a>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**B.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
.spoiler {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.contentBoxFooter{position:absolute;bottom:10px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="x" class="spoiler">Content1</div> 
    <div id="y" class="spoiler">Content2</div>
    <div id="z" class="spoiler">Content3</div>
    <div class="contentBoxFooter">
        <a href="#x" class = "spoilerButton">Show/Hide</a>
        <a href="#y" class = "spoilerButton">Show/Hide</a>
        <a href="#z" class = "spoilerButton">Show/Hide</a>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".spoilerButton").click(function (e) { 
            e.preventDefault()
            var foo=$(this).attr('href')
            $(''+foo).slideToggle(1000); 
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Update: here's the example of what I need: https://support.google.com/plus/#topic=3049663 each section adds a unique URL ending to the link.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Have you played with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644654/parse-url-with-jquery-javascript in order to get the `x` from `B.html#x`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have updated my question above to show what I have tried. I'm sorry, I haven't tried the solution you provided, but it seems like not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/accordion-open-a-specific-tab-with-link-from-another-page

But I ended up with the accordion, instead of a set of spoilers, as I initially wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t like to do it over the querying the url, you need to open `B.html` in a new javascript `window`.

And there you can do something it, e. g.:

```
window win = window.open("B.html");
win.document.myVariable = "test";
```

Then you could read the variable on website B.html as you usually would do with `myVariable`

Edit: If you just want to load page `B.html` into a spoiler in page `A.html` then it´s just a single jquery command:

```
$("#spoiler").load("B.html");
```